# Clean table for duplicates and keep the newest

Tags: mysql

We got an table with timestamps, coords, ids and events.
I'd like to clean my table in the way so that one duplicate of each coordinate (X, Y, Z) is kept (the newest one with `place` as event, cleaning all `break` events).

**decayworld (table):**

```
+------------+-----------+-----+----+-----+------+
| Created    | EventName | X   | Y  | Z   | id   |
+------------+-----------+-----+----+-----+------+
| 1515700748 | break     | -64 | 82 | 229 | 4110 |
| 1515700749 | place     | -64 | 82 | 229 | 4111 |
| 1515700750 | break     | -64 | 82 | 229 | 4112 |
| 1515700750 | place     | -64 | 82 | 229 | 4113 |
| 1515700751 | break     | -64 | 82 | 229 | 4114 |
| 1515700751 | place     | -64 | 82 | 229 | 4115 |
+------------+-----------+-----+----+-----+------+
```

**What's wrong with the following code?**

```
DELETE from decayworld where EventName='break';

DELETE a
FROM decayworld a
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT MAX(id) id, Created, EventName, X, Y, Z
 FROM decayworld
  GROUP BY X, Y, Z
) b ON a.Created = b.Created AND
a.X = b.X and
a.Y = b.Y AND
a.Z = b.Z AND
a.EventName = b.EventName and 
a.id = b.id
WHERE b.ID IS NULL;

select * from decayworld;
```

**Result (the issue):**
All rows get cleaned.

**Desired output:**

```
+------------+-----------+-----+----+-----+------+
| Created    | EventName | X   | Y  | Z   | id   |
+------------+-----------+-----+----+-----+------+
| 1515700751 | place     | -64 | 82 | 229 | 4115 |
+------------+-----------+-----+----+-----+------+
```

Comment: can you add the desired output in form of a table like you did for the input data so it is easier to understand what you are going for? thnx

Comment: That's no problem - added :)

Comment: There's nothing in your code that distinguishes between `place` and `break` events.

Comment: Because I clean all `break` events first like you see. There's no need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By including `Created` and `EventName` in the `SELECT` and `JOIN`, those columns may be coming from different rows than the maximum of the group, so the join might not find anything that matches all criteria. The proper way is:

```
DELETE a
FROM decayworld AS a
JOIN (SELECT X, Y, Z, MAX(id) AS id
      FROM decayworld
      GROUP BY X, Y, Z) AS b
ON a.X = b.X
AND a.Y = b.Y
AND a.Z = b.Z
AND a.id < b.id
```